# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have written a WPF application, on my compuyter it is running ok. 
Now I am trying to deploy wpf application on W7 computer. And getting following exception:

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(System.Exception, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at CAMXSimulator.App.Main()
```

Any idea what is wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: i'm having the exact same exception and cannot start my app on some Windows (worked on some..), have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I have the same issue. We installed our app on a VM computer and we connect remote desktop to it and 2 out of 8 accounts works the rest get that error. all account are admin and run the same exact exe on the computer. So i know it is no code related. It's a user right somewhere that is missing. FYI all account are part of local administrator group.

Comment: This is why I hate XAML.

Answer (score 10):

This type of exception is common when some part of your main window constructor or load operations fail.  If you can get your hands on the stack trace, look to the inner exception and you will probably find the real issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem because I was showing a form from in Application constructor. This form was using Style="{StaticResource XYZ}". This static resource was defined in the application's XAML file.

I solved the problem by showing the form at a later stage in the application, when the Application object was fully constructed.

Comment: many thanks for your explanation - have same problem, solution - exactly the same as you sad here, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same exception report. I could solve it by using the `windbg` program.

- download the [windbg x86](http://codemachine.com/downloads.html) (not x64) version.
- open the .exe file of the app in it (File menu -> open exe.)
- run these commands to see the real exception:

After the analysis, I found that the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` assembly was missing from the system.

```
0:000> g
0:000> sxe clr
0:000> g
0:000> !loadby sos clr
0:000> !CLRStack
0:000> !PrintException

Exception type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    InnerException: <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

the only thing I can think of is whether both boxes have same .NET version on it. NET 4 has some new features (re XAML parser) that 3.5 SP1 doesnt have

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a similar behavior when installing a ClickOnce app on a clean machine. I solved by setting the requirements of the app for install both .Net 4 and .Net 3.5 full.

It was not happened anymore.

Comment: I am having the exact same exception. But in VS2010 I can only target one FrameWork (3.5 or 4), but not BOTH. What do you mean by "both"? I installed both 3.5 and 4 FrameWork but the app still doesn't seem to start.

Comment: For "both" I mean the application "Prerequisites" in the "Publish" properties page. For instance, I have an app targeted for .Net 4 (full), but also needs .Net 2 (due a 3rd-party dll). In the "Prerequisites" list I checked: 3.5-SP1, 4, 4-Client Profile.
However, I am pretty sure this is not the right way to choose those boxes!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are build in the correct architecture x86 or x64 when you run on the target machine. I face the same problem as well, the app able to run on my thumbdrive FAT32 however it failed on another machine with Windows 7 - 32bit (I know Windows 7 with 32bit is quite odd though) see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8f803f28-dfda-4be5-9e8d-f7d82db95961/c-wpf-systemwindowsmarkupxamlparseexception?forum=wpf